# Laravel5: Why my model "Media" require table named "media" instead of "medias"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

From the [doc of laravel](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent), it claims:

> Now, let's look at an example `Flight` model, which we will use to retrieve and store information from our `flights` database table

So I wrote:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Media extends Model
{
    //
}
```

And controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Media;

class MediaController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('medias.index')->with('medias', Media::all());
    }
}
```

But when I query `MediaController@index`, it gives that error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myapp.media' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `media`)
```

It requires a table named `media` instead of `medias` as document said. So why that errors happened? Do I accidentally open option flag which changed the default name mapping from model to table or something similar?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

---

Environment:

- Laravel Framework version 5.2.43
- PHP 7.0.8-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1

Comment: Show your query please. Also, do you use `protected $table` variable in the model?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin see my edit

Comment: the plural of media is media not medias, laravel is smart enough to know this :)

Comment: @Sayakiss You renamed the table, also check for foreign key constraints for this into the table

Comment: Laravel works on the basis of a "default" table name, but you can manually override this in your model definition and use whatever name you want (within the limitations of your database rules)

Comment: Simply changing the table name wont help. You can define the table name in the model as posted in the answer below. This will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @FrankProvost said, Laravel (Doctrine, actually) is smart enough and has [hardcoded words that should not be inflected](https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php#L211):

```
....
'Kongoese', 'Lucchese', 'mackerel', 'Maltese', '.*?media',
....
```

So, use `media` table or use [`protected $table`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models) variable to force `medias` table name.

Comment: @Sayakiss **media** is actually the plural of **medium**

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your table is named "medias" in your model "media", try to specify in Class.

```
class Media extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'medias';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your table is named "medias" in your model "media",
you need to define protected variable like this

```
class Media extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'medias';
}
```